# Ionic view only with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I've installed ionic and its example app manage the view with this two code:

App.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
url: "/tab",
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:
.state('tab.dash', {
url: '/dash',
views: {
  'tab-dash': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
    controller: 'DashCtrl'
  }
}
})

.state('tab.chats', {
  url: '/chats',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
      controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tab.chat-detail', {
  url: '/chats/:chatId',
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
      controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.account', {
url: '/account',
views: {
  'tab-account': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
    controller: 'AccountCtrl'
  }
}
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

<!-- Dashboard Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Chats Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

<!-- Account Tab -->
<ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

If, for example, I write something in a input in a tab, when I change tab and when I go back, my "something" is always in the input.

How Can I use this method only with AngularJS, without Ionic?

---

**EDIT 2:**
I've tried with this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ui-view="state1"></div>
<div ui-view="state2"></div>
<a ui-sref="state1">State1</a> - <a ui-sref="state2">State2</a>
</body>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');

        $stateProvider
                .state('state1',{
                    url: "/state1",
                    views: {
                        'state1': {
                            template: 'State 1: <input type="text">'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('state2',{
                    url: "/state2",
                    views: {
                        'state2': {
                            template: 'State 2: <input type="text">'
                        }
                    }
                })
    });
</script>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work.
Ionic use a similar method, I think, and it works.
I need to create two (or more) view that keep changes and input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use service or factory to pass data between states please see demo here #

http://plnkr.co/edit/rPpZhbpns7OUeZURJNJQ?p=preview

ie:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.factory('RandomFactory', function() {
  return "Hello there";
});

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
      url: "/state1",
      templateUrl: "state1.html",
      controller: function($scope, dataService) {

        $scope.user = dataService.user;

      }
    })

  .state('state2', {
    url: "/state2/",
    templateUrl: "state2.html",
    controller: function($scope, dataService) {

      $scope.user = dataService.user;
    }

  });


});

myApp.factory('dataService', function() {

  var user = {};
  return {
    user: user
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried using two view. I've edit my question, my new test doesn't work...